# How does the introduction of clones would affect population genetics?

Tags: evolution, homework, population-genetics, conservation-biology

Since the ability to clone animals gives another way to preserve species, this could help for the breeding process. It has been noted that with the ability to clone animals, endangered species can have their population numbers increased in a short time. How would this impact these population from the perspective of genetics/ the gene pool?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. Is this a homework question?

Comment: yes it is @Remi.b

Comment: The title should be the main question quickly phrased and should not set the field of study. Obviously saying "it is a biology question" is really not helpful as everything on this site is about biology.

Comment: Then, you should always show your effort to try to answer the question otherwise the question is off-topic. I will vote to close as you haven't shown your efforts to answer the question and will remove the vote close as soon as you added this info. You can have a look at the homerwork [question policy here](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework).

Comment: Since the ability to clone animals gives another way to persevere species, this could help for the breeding process. Cloning helps to be alternative route for the genetic line and helps with endangered species to be save and increased.

Comment: You should add this comment into your question so that others will directly see what efforts you've produced. Try to come up with as many thoughts as possible. Despite showing that you are not just asking for "someone else to do your job", it also helps to target what may be unclear to you.

Comment: @kristy **I have prepared an answer for you but, as this is homework, I would like to see more effort from you, some tips for you to think about:** How do you think cloning could be used? Why would cloning be useful? Where can cloning step in? Why would this impact genetic variation?

Comment: @Kristy The question is on the verge of being closed, if that happens I can't post the answer unless it gets reopened - that will only happen if you make some edits to show that you've given some thought to the reasons that cloning may or may not be useful. It's otherwise a good question and I'd like to provide the answer